# time in wrong time zone when using get

Tags: 8

I have a date/time field, when I save it as 1:00:00 AM, it displays in the edit form as 1:00 am, however when I do a get of that field value in my module
with `$posted_date=$static_media->get('field_pup_posted')->getValue();`

, it comes out as`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 2017-06-14T05:00:00
        )

)`

Why is it being stored as a 5 when it should be a 1?  and how can i get it programatically in the correct time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drupal stores in UTC have to convert this to current time zone

```
$dt=new \DateTime($changed_date, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$correct_date =  $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```